# Blender: split object with a shape

Tags: blender, modeling

I've got a flat object that I want to split in multiple pieces (background: I want to print it later, but the surface of my printer is not large enough). I've modeled a simple puzzle-shape:

[image]

I would like to use this shape to cut through my object, but if I use the boolean modifier, blender generates vertexes where the shape and the object intersects, but it won't cut the object since my shape got a thickness of 0:

[image] I don't want to make my shape thicker, because otherwise it would delete something of my object...

Answer (score 0):

You are able to separate the two sides of the object from each other, and then rejoin them afterwards if you need to. (This does include the use of the boolean modifier)

First, you should add the boolean modifier to the main mesh where you want it, with the 'difference' operation. Then in edit mode, as you explained before, the vertexes are created but there isn't the actual 'cut' that you were looking for.

I recreated the scenario with a plane intersecting a cube:
[image: I recreated the scenario with a plane intersecting a cube]

This is what it looks like in edit mode after having applied the boolean modifier:
[image: This is what it looks like in edit mode after having applied the boolean modifier]

Second what you can do is (after applying the boolean modifier) select the faces you want to be separated in edit mode. Then, pressing P (shortcut for separate, you can get to it by right clicking) click on 'selection' and you should have two separate objects. One of the objects will have what looks like a missing face: If you wanted two separate objects, then you just need to add a face on the object with the missing face and you can look no further. If you wanted separate parts of objects that are separate within edit mode (all together one object in object mode) then you can select the two objects and press crtl+j. Hope this helps somehwhat!

I have selected half of the cube that I want cut out (the selection does not include the face in the middle):
[image: I have selected half of the cube that I want cut out (the selection does not include the face in the middle)]

There are now two objects, completely seperated from each other:
[image: There are now two objects, completely seperated from each other]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately I want to split more complex structures than the example that I've shown. When I tried your method it was impossible to select the faces, since blender did not split some faces along the cutting pattern. I guess I'll try to extrude the pattern and keep it as thin as possible.

Comment: Applying the boolean modifier in the first step does not create the split line at all.